# How can I generate a cookie file from Watir cookies

Tags: ruby, watir, typhoeus

I am trying to download a file from Watir but I don't want to use the `loop sleep` approach.

I would rather at the last moment of the interaction, recreate the session Watir has on the webpage and use another library, for example Typhoeus.

Typhoeus uses curl and can use cookies from a file, nonetheless, Watir generates a Hash Array, and if I ask to save it, it saves it as a YAML file.

Is there a faster way to convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another article in StackOverflow said that curl uses [Mozilla style cookie files](https://xiix.wordpress.com/2006/03/23/mozillafirefox-cookie-format/).

So, if your Watir instance is `browser` and the file to which you are going to write to is `file` you can do

```
browser.cookies.to_a.each do |ch| 
  terms = []
  terms << ch[:domain]
  terms << ch[:same_site].nil? ? 'FALSE' : 'TRUE'
  terms << ch[:path]
  terms << ch[:secure] ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'
  terms << ch[:expires].to_i.to_s
  terms << ch[:name]
  terms << ch[:value]
  file.puts terms.join("\t")
end
```

Then you can tell Typhoeus to use the contents of `file` to keep navigating using the same cookies.